# Какие файлы хранить в git, а какие нет

Tags: git, ide

Добрый день, коллеги. Есть вопрос:
Нужно ли мне хранить файлы настройки для проекта в git, относящиеся только к ide?

например, чтобы добавить в idea  проект с git, указав ссылку на репозиторий. Должны ли быть закоммичены файлы от ide

Comment: однозначно нет  
все генерируемые и энвайронмент-зависимые файлы храниться не должны  
файлы-шаблоны для создания энвайронмент-зависимых файлов - должны

Answer (score 1):

Однозначно нет. На то она и система контроля версий что бы за версиями исходников следить. Докладывать же служебные файлы среды разработки - плохой тон.

1) Не обязательно что ваша среда и именно ваша версия используется и другими разработчиками, которые подключены к репозиторию.

2) Информационной нагрузки они так же не несут. Уж если там есть какие-то специфические моменты конфигурации, то их лучше вынести в readme.txt

Comment: Совершенно не однозначно. Если на проекте принят, к примеру, Eclipse, то положить туда же файл workplace будет очень уместно, чтобы любой новый разработчик не настраивал себе всё окружение для сборки проекта по какой-то странице в wiki, а сразу же смог работать, а если кто-то из коллег добавил в зависимости от сборки какую-то библиотеку, то она сразу бы появилась в зависимостях и у остальных при обновлении.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на ваш вопрос в своё время я нашёл на [гитхабе](http://dotfiles.github.io/). Абсолютно правильного решения нет, тк существует множество вариантов (одиночная разработка, в команде). Но всегда можно подглядеть как работают другие и перенять их опыт.

ps: .idea у меня всегда в .gitignore